# Disable date range on html datepicker for Safari iOS

Tags: html, ios, angular, datepicker

I need to restrict date for my datepicker, so that people who are under 16 can't select their birthdate.

The issue I got is with Safari iOS. The application will be used mainly on an ipad but the "min/max" option are not compatible with Safari :   [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Is there another way to restrict date without using min/max ?

Here is my code for the moment:

```
      <input class="form-control" 
             [required]="isRequired('Birthdate','birthdate')" 
             type="date" [max]="maxDate" 
             jhiTranslate="form.birthdate.placeholder"
             ngModel name="birthdate" #birthdate="ngModel">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution?